# Исключения из OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Есть VPS с сервером OpenVPN, с домашнего ПК через него подключаюсь. Но проблема в том, что некоторые IP нужно исключить из маршрута через VPN, так, чтобы они шли минуя туннель. Можно-ли это сделать средствами OpenVPN, поскольку route в windows не дает никакого результата + те-же исключения нужны на android

Comment: Поддержка `OpenVPN` прекращается 30 апреля. Советую отказаться от его использования.

Comment: Никакой информации об этом я не нашел

Comment: https://3dnews.ru/968617

Comment: Вы ошиблись, новость про OperaVPN